# How to test printing from iPhone App if we do not have AirPrint enabled Printers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, airprint

Is there a way to test whether correct pages are being passed for printing from iPhone App if we do not have AirPrint enabled printers?

Please let me know.

Comment: Buy a printer? They can be had fairly cheaply and you'd be crazy not to test on a real device.

Comment: Agreed. But what can we do if its urgent to test? Is there a way out?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can actually test printing in the simulator, somewhere in the setting (sorry, not near my computer at the moment) there is an option to turn on the print server. When you test it will output a PDF.

Comment: In the iOS simulator, file menu, Open print simulator.

Comment: You can also find it from xcode directly in the Xcode menu-> Open Developer Tool->Printer Simulator

Comment: @sosborn: This option doesn't show in xcode6 with ios7 or ios8 simulator!!! Is there any other way for this?

Comment: Xcode 6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030702/where-is-printer-simulator-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 8):

In the iOS simulator look under the File menu. You'll find "Open Printer Simulator". This will provide several different simulated printers.

Answer (score 6):

Since Xcode 6 you have to download it separately:
[Hardware IO Tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-6#)

> This package includes additional hardware i/o tools formerly bundled in the Xcode installer. These tools include: Apple Bluetooth Guidelines Validation, Bluetooth Explorer, HomeKit Accessory Simulator, IO Registry Explorer, Network Link Conditioner.prefpane, PacketLogger and Printer Simulator. These graphic tools support running on OS X 10.10 and OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do some [setup](http://netpatia.blogspot.com/2011/07/airprint-in-corporate-networks.html) to share any conventional printer as if it were a real AirPrint printer.