# Where is printer simulator in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, printing, simulator

I remember on Xcode 5 the simulator has a button called "Open Printer Simulator" locate in File menu but now it is gone.

How can I test printer on the simulator?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think its not coming with default Xcode package. You have to install it separately. In the [apple developer downloads section](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) (You have to login first) find the **Hardware IO Tools for Xcode**

[image]

Comment: ```{"responseId":"57d710ec-eb15-410c-9277-27bcbd61982b","resultCode":1003,"resultString":"request.uri.notfound","userString":"Invalid request, Service mapping to the requested URL is not available. ","creationTimestamp":"2016-08-01T07:39:19Z","userLocale":"en_US","requestUrl":"https://developer.apple.com:443/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-","httpCode":200,"suppressed":[]}```

Answer (score 9):

As of Xcode 8, the printer simulator is now found under "Additional Tools for Xcode" rather than "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode":

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: The `Additional Tools for Xcode` now does not appear (nor is searchable) unless you use the `for Xcode` query param:   https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode