# How to create virtual printer with iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, ios10, printers, xcode8.2

In one of my application there is feature to print documents. I want to test this feature but I don’t have device, So I have to test on Simulator. With simulator how can I print documents. Do I need to connect physical printer or can I create virtual printer and test with it ?

I am using `Xcode 8.2.1`, `iOS 10` and `StarPrint iOS SDK 5.2.1`

I have searched lot but I didn’t find which work for me. How can I do that ?

I have referred below links :

1. [Where is printer simulator in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030702/where-is-printer-simulator-in-xcode-6)
2. [Here I cannot find hardware tools for Xcode 8.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode)

Answer (score 26):

The Simulator should be able to see any AirPrint compatible printer that you Mac can see.

1. You can use a simulated printer. Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.
2. Download "Additional Tools for Xcode 8.x" corresponding to your version.
3. Install the package.
4. Start Printer Simulator

Printer Simulator will automatically register several simulated printers as long as it is running. They will show up in the iOS printer selection view. They also show up to other Macs on your network and even physical iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks for answer, let me try.

Comment: Second time I'm finding this answer.. :) Thanks!

Comment: Note that the URL has changed to: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/