# How to fake an AirPrint printer

Tags: c#, printing, bonjour, airprint, virtual-printer

I want to write (preferably in C# but that is not essential, and preferably on Windows though, again, that is not essential) something that looks to iOS devices to be an AirPrint printer. I want the iOS device user experience to be as it would be if it was really dealing with an AirPrint printer. I want to be able to get the output to be printed as pdf document and something to identify the user. I want to store the output for later printing. I hope someone can point me in the direction of some documentation or learning materials that will help me achieve this. I've done a lot of browsing online and have drawn a blank. There are utilities that make non-AirPrint printers discoverable by iOS so I presume what I want to do can be achieved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928387/how-to-create-virtual-printer-with-ios-simulator?noredirect=1

Comment: Ian, did you manage to write a C# ipp server that works with AirPrint?

Comment: @IPPNerd I did, but take very little credit for it as it's closely based on ippserver. I don't have a profound understanding of the protocol so copied the request parsing code from ippserver and pasted it into an ASP.NET Web Api controller post method and carefully converted it to C#. I was pretty amazed how well it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/istopwg/ippsample. ippserver is treated as an AirPrint printer with specific options and minor adjustments, which are well documented elsewhere.